# I need to modify this repository

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg, telegram-bot

I got this telegram audio extracter bot repository from [GitHub](https://github.com/TroJanzHEX/Streams-Extractor). This bot extract and convert the audio to MP3. but I want to extract the audio in native format without Re Encoding.. I can do it in ffmpeg.. but with python I can't understand.. what changes will make this work..?

```
from helpers.tools import execute, clean_up
from helpers.upload import upload_audio, upload_subtitle

async def extract_audio(client, message, data):
    await message.edit_text("Extracting Stream from file...")

    dwld_loc = data['location']
    out_loc = data['location'] + ".mp3"

    if data['name'] == "mp3":
        out, err, rcode, pid = await execute(f"ffmpeg -i '{dwld_loc}' -map 0:{data['map']} -c copy '{out_loc}' -y")
        if rcode != 0:
            await message.edit_text("**Error Occured. See Logs for more info.**")
            print(err)
            await clean_up(dwld_loc, out_loc)
            return
    else:
        out, err, rcode, pid = await execute(f"ffmpeg -i '{dwld_loc}' -map 0:{data['map']} '{out_loc}' -y")
        if rcode != 0:
            await message.edit_text("**Error Occured. See Logs for more info.**")
            print(err)
            await clean_up(dwld_loc, out_loc)
            return

    await clean_up(dwld_loc)
    await upload_audio(client, message, out_loc)
```

Comment: What is a native audio format without encoding? Basically every format in a computer is encoded.

Comment: Sry.. I want to extract same audio format from input file. Without re encoding or converting (copy)..